# How to host MVC app inside another MVC app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have 2 applications written in MVC 4. ex:

www.website1.com

www.website2.com

I want to host website2 inside website1. This means I want website2 to be navigated like : www.website1.com/website2

I did following to achieve this :

1) Published Website1 code to folder "Website1" inside iis. This has its web.config.

2) Published Website2 code to folder "Website1/Website2" inside iis. This has its web.config.

3) Converted both sites to applications inside IIS.

4) Now I am able to navigate to "www.website1.com" but when I navigate to www.website1.com/website2 , 
**its not loading any css or javascript** **?** **I see just the html in browser.**

_Layout file in website 2 has a line like this   @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")

But when I look in IE developer tools , I see path as : /Website1/Website2/Content/bootstrap.css

I manually changed this /Website1/Website2/Content/bootstrap.css to /Website2/Content/bootstrap.css and it was able to load the css.

Question is why it is referring to website1 ? and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you looked at Areas ?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you can add a virtual directory (named Website2) inside Website1 and add all content of Website2 there.

Anyway having two Web.config files won't work, you will have to move all configurations of Website2 into Web.config file in the root of Website1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using following in parent web config .

Just put it around the block that you don't want to inherit in child app.

```
 <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" >
</location>
```